# How to output only the "--pretty=" part of git rev-list?

Tags: git, git-rev-list

`git rev-list --pretty='%H %an <%ae> %at' origin/topic-branch ^origin/master`

outputs the following:

```
commit d2d0b50ceac50cc81cf991ce09ab3db134af751d
d2d0b50ceac50cc81cf991ce09ab3db134af751d John Doe <john@doe.com> 1592392426
commit c5e1438a6ef2e6090c3f9dd9df0a5834b32b50b1
c5e1438a6ef2e6090c3f9dd9df0a5834b32b50b1 John Doe <john@doe.com> 1592393061
```

The desired output should include only the string comprised by the placeholders in the pretty format, like this:

```
d2d0b50ceac50cc81cf991ce09ab3db134af751d John Doe <john@doe.com> 1592392426
c5e1438a6ef2e6090c3f9dd9df0a5834b32b50b1 John Doe <john@doe.com> 1592393061
```

I do not know how to get rid of the default lines printed by `rev-list`.

Comment: You can pipe in the output of git rev-list and add a grep query for lines not starting with the word `commit`

Comment: Indeed, I can pipe with `| grep -v "^commit"` but I was wondering if there is an out of the box solution in git, as I would need to write more commands like this soon.

Comment: When you specify a format explicitly the only difference between rev-list and log is the absence of that header line. So you could just use `git log --pretty='%H %an <%ae %at' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git rev-list origin/topic-branch ^origin/master |
    while read sha1; do
        git --no-pager show -s --pretty='%H %an <%ae> %at'
    done
```

The main part of the trick is `git show -s` which skips commit headers and only print the pretty part.